# Show linkbutton inside Repeater active on click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0

Generate A to Z linkbutton, I want to show alphabet linkbutton Active on Click. Either by Jquery or Code Behind.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptAlphabets" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAlphabet" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Value")%>'  OnClick="Alphabet_Click" CssClass="listbtn" Width="31px" Height="15px" align="center"  CommandName="getalphabet" />

                <div class="clear-list">
                </div>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater> 
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rptAlphabets" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Let's clear up - onclick or on hover? If on click how exactly is should look like?

Comment: Need to work when "Click".Set/Change Background Color on Click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to highlight the selected button out of the groyp.. Yes you can do it using the CSS and JQuery..

use the below snippet...

```
 <style>
    .listbtn {
        border: 1px solid #bbb;
        border-radius: 2px;
        background-color: #eee;
        text-decoration: none;

        width: auto!important;
        padding: 3px;
    }
    .selected {
        background-color: #222;
        color: white;
    }
</style>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.listbtn').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.listbtn').each(function () {
                $(this).removeClass('selected');
            });
            $(this).addClass('selected');

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Inspect Element it show dynamic id 
when i click alphabet G : id = #rptAlphabets_ctl06_lnkAlphabet
when i click alphabet B : id = #rptAlphabets_ctl01_lnkAlphabet 
and so on.... this prevent linkbutton to be active.

Comment: thats why in the above code i used the `class` not the `id`

Comment: it should work like the given example.. [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/n18qpjbg/)

Comment: your code works but on click doesnot gives me any result,just highlighting the linkbuttons.Now linkbutton doesn't fire

Comment: its because I have used the `e.preventDefault();` just uncomment that line and bind your own javascript method calling.  I used **e.preventDefault()** else it will refresh the page and the **highlighting** the button will also get fresh and u will not able to see any highlighted button.. hope its clear to u as its very basic term of html/js and css

Comment: Yes I did before you said, but what should i bind, i am getting dynamic linkbutton id's

Comment: but when I said to use or bind the ID? sa u already told u getting dynamic thats why only I used the class not id. even I already specified the same line earlier also.

Comment: Working brother.. sorry issue was related to asyncpostback solved now..thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused. But the code to enable a button would be something like.
    Button1.enabled=false;
    if(checkbox.checked)
    {
    Button1.enabled=true;
    }

Comment: but linkbutton is inside Repeater, it generate dynamic id everytime click is changed 

eg: in Inspectelement i am geting something like this, 

when i click alphabet A : id = #rptAlphabets_ctl00_lnkAlphabet when i click alphabet B : id = #rptAlphabets_ctl01_lnkAlphabet
.
.
When alphabet Z is Click id = #rptAlphabets_ctl25_lnkAlphabet